# Best way to save large column data in datawarehouse

Tags: oracle, clob, dimension, dimensional-modeling

I have a table that stores the changes to a transaction. All the changes are captured into a table. One of the column that comes as part of the transaction can have many comma separated values. The number of occurrences cannot be predicted. Also this field is not mandatory and can have null values as well.

The total number of transactions that i have in the table is around 100M. Out of those the number of records for which the value is populated is 1M. Out of the 1M transactions the number of records for which the length of the record exceeds 4000 is ~37K.

I mentioned the length as 4000 since in my oracle table the column which would save this has been defined as varchar2(4000).

I check at places and found that if I have to save something of unknown length then i should define the table column datatype as clob. But clob is expensive for me since only a very small amount of data has length > 4000. If I snowflake my star schema and create another table to store the values then even though, I have transactions for which the length is much smaller than 4000 would be saved as part of the clob column. This would be expensive both in terms of storage and performance.

Can someone suggest me an approach to solve this problem.

Thanks
S

Comment: Hi - what is the analytical value of this column that may or may not hold an unknown number of comma-separated elements - and how is it being used in your reports/BI? If it has no analytical value then why are you holding it in your dimensional model?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a master - detail table to store the comma separated values,  then you could have rows rather than save all comma separated values in a single column. This could be managed with a foregn key using a pseudo key between master and detail table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option.

Create two columns, e.g.

```
create table storage
  (id          number primary key,
   long_text_1 varchar2(4000),
   long_text_2 varchar2(4000)
  );
```

Store values like

```
insert into storage (id, long_text_1, long_text_2)
  values (seq.nextval,
          substr(input_value,    1, 4000),
          substr(input_value, 4001, 4000)
         );
```

When retrieving them from the table, concatenate them:

```
select id,
       long_text_1 || long_text_2 as long_text
from storage
where ...
```

Comment: yes thought of this option but.. since only a handful of records exceed the max length, will it not be a redundant column for majority of the records.

Comment: So what? It won't occupy any significant space. NULL value will take just one (1) byte to indicate that column's size is zero (0).

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from using inline SecurFile CLOBs. With inline CLOBs, up to about 4000 bytes of data can be stored in rows like a regular VARCHAR2 and only the larger values will be stored in a separate CLOB segment. With SecureFiles, Oracle can significantly improve CLOB performance. (For example, import and export of SecureFiles is much faster than the old-fashioned BasicFile LOB format.)

Depending on your version, parameters, and table DDL, your database may already store CLOBs as inline SecureFiles. Ensure that your COMPATIBLE setting is 11.2 or higher, and that DB_SECUREFILE is one of "permitted", "always", or "preferred":

```
select name, value from v$parameter where name in ('compatible', 'db_securefile') order by 1;
```

Use a query like this to ensure that your tables were setup correctly, and nobody overrode the system settings:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME') from dual;
```

You should see something like this in the results:

```
... LOB ("CLOB_NAME") STORE AS SECUREFILE (... ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW ...) ...
```

One of the main problems with CLOBs is that they are stored in a separate segment, and a LOB index must be traversed to map each row in the table to a value in another segment. The below demo creates two tables to show that LOB segments do not need to be used when the the data is small and stored inline.

```
--drop table clob_test_inline;
--drop table clob_test_not_in;
create table clob_test_inline(a number, b clob) lob(b) store as securefile (enable storage in row);
create table clob_test_not_in(a number, b clob) lob(b) store as (disable storage in row);

insert into clob_test_inline select level, lpad('A', 900, 'A') from dual connect by level <= 10000;
insert into clob_test_not_in select level, lpad('A', 900, 'A') from dual connect by level <= 10000;
commit;
```

The inline table segment is large, because it holds all the data. The out of line table segment is small, because all of its data is held elsewhere.

```
select segment_name, bytes/1024/1024 mb_inline
from dba_segments
where segment_name like 'CLOB_TEST%'
order by 1;

SEGMENT_NAME       MB_INLINE
----------------   ---------
CLOB_TEST_INLINE      27
CLOB_TEST_NOT_IN       0.625
```

Looking at the LOB segments, the sizes are reversed. The inline table doesn't store anything in the LOB segment.

```
select table_name, bytes/1024/1024 mb_out_of_line
from dba_segments
join dba_lobs
    on dba_segments.owner = dba_lobs.owner
    and dba_segments.segment_name = dba_lobs.segment_name
where dba_lobs.table_name like 'CLOB_TEST%'
order by 1;

TABLE_NAME          MB_OUT_OF_LINE
------------        --------------
CLOB_TEST_INLINE            0.125
CLOB_TEST_NOT_IN           88.1875
```

Despite the above, I can't promise that CLOBs will still work for you. All I can say is that it's worth testing the data using CLOBs. You'll still need to look out for a few things. CLOBs store text slightly differently (UCS2 instead of UTF8), which may take up more space depending on your character sets. So check the segment sizes. But also beware that segment sizes can lie when they are small - there's a lot of auto-allocated overhead for sample data, so you'll want to use realistic sizes when testing.

Finally, as Raul pointed out, storing non-atomic values in a field is usually a terrible mistake. That said, there are rare times when data warehouses need to break the rules for performance, and data needs to be stored as compactly as possible. Before you store the data this way, ensure that you will never need to join based on those values, or query for individual values. If you think dealing with 100M rows is tough, just wait until you try to split 100M values and then join them to another table.